# Get 5 next birthdays including next year

Tags: mysql

I have this query that takes the next 5 people who have a birthday.

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d') > date_format(curdate(), '%m-%d')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d')
LIMIT 5
```

Working great but when it's for example `12 december` it does not take the people from the next year 12 `january`.

How could I do this?

Comment: What type is `birth_date`? `DATETIME`?

Comment: How about `>=`?

Comment: Does `birth_date` also store the year?

Comment: Yes `birt_date` stores the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't work because:
 1. You only compare Month and Day and don't compare Year. You also should compare Year
 2. You should calculate the next date of birthday.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE (birth_date + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(birth_date) + IF(DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) >= DAYOFYEAR(birth_date), 1, 0)) YEAR) > CURDATE()
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d')
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: If our OP stores year in the birthday, Order by must be extended to %Y as WHERE condition

Comment: I store `birth_date` with year.

Comment: I didn't run this, I'm just mentally compiling, but doesn't this only return unborn babies?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I made a mistake in my answer. I corrected it.

Comment: @MaximFedorov for some reason this does not work with birthdate `1983-01-14` if a user has this birthdate it will always show up ? Very strange!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need to take the months, and add 12 to any months that are greater or equal to the current month, and this should give you a recursive month order:

```
select name,
    month(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, "%m-%d")) AS birth_month,
    if(
        month(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, "%m-%d")) >= month(now()),
        month(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, "%m-%d")),
        month(STR_TO_DATE(birth_date, "%m-%d")) + 12
    ) month_order
from `user`
order by month_order
limit 5
```

The `STR_TO_DATE` isn't needed if you're using `DATETIME`

> **Note:** This won't work for multiple years in a row. Just into the next year.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not working I get wrong birthdates back.

Comment: Could you http://sqlfiddle.com/ what you're seeing? I tested this and it worked from the data that I had. A sample set would be extremely useful

Comment: Sure one moment.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I go with @aximFedorov works great too :)